# add edit button to each row in html table, to edit database

Tags: php, html

I am relatively new to php, and need help with a program i am doing for an internship... on the page i am trying to create, i queried all records in the mysql database, and inserted them into an html table. What i am trying to do, is also add an edit button in a separate column of each row of the table, so the rows can be edited.. i know how to get the button there, but i do not know how i can get the values out of that particular row, into a php variable so i can perform more queries to edit, delete, etc... I have been looking for a couple days, and it looks like it may be possible to do with javascript, but i have never used javascript before, so i do not know what im looking at... help would be much appreciated

basically:

```
<html>
<table border="1">

<th>Suspended</th>
<th>Device Name</th>
<th>IP</th>
<th>Depend</th>
<th>Email</th>

<?php
$sql = "select * from table;"

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
echo "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td><td>".$row[3]."       </td><td>".$row[4]."</td></tr>";
}
?>

</table>
</html>
```

==I have not really tried anything yet for the edit/delete buttons.. i dont really know where to start

Comment: A good read :: [what have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com). As to your issue, there are multiple ways. One way is javascript, another is each row is its own submit-able form or some other. Its your call.

Comment: could you possibly give me an example on the javascript that would work??? and that is basically what i have as the table... im at home, and the program is on my server at the office, so i cant look at it at the moment... the query and table works just fine also... just cant figure out how an edit button would work, such as, if i clicked the button, how could i grab just that record on that particular row of the button... if that makes any sense

Answer (score 2):

For each of the edit buttons create a form with a hidden field that stores a uniquely identifiable id for that row (a primary key value).

```
<form action="editPage.php" method="post/get">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row_id; ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Edit"/>
</form>
```

Then use the id to update the fields for that record in the database.

What is `$row_id`? and how to use $rowvalue if i want to insert it to variable or session?

Comment: is there any way i can add a value to a button, which would be the primary key of that particular row, and when clicked, takes me to another page where i can post the button value to a php variable??? if that is possible, i could then perform any query i needed